# BOOTSTRAP 5 CARDS IMAGE

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have bootstrap card with image on the right side. However the image does not entirely fill the side.

[Here is the image of my bootstrap card][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7xuT.png

This is my code for the card:

```html
{% for book in thesis_details %}
                        <div class="card m-3" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
                          <div class="row g-0">

                            <div class="col-md-4">  
                                <div class="card-image">
                                {% if book.image_banner %}
                                    <img src="{{book.image_banner.url}}" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
                                {% else %}                      
                                    <img src="{% static 'images/placeholder.png' %}" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
                                {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-8">  
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <h2 class="card-title">{{book.title}}</h2>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Published by: {{book.author}}</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle pt-1">Course: {{book.course}}</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">{{book.abstract|safe|slice:":310"}}...</p>
                                <a href="/view_studthesis/{{book.thesis_id}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger float-bottom" style="">View more</button></a>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

And my css:

```css
/* for cards */
.card{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
}

.card-image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-image img{
  object-fit: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you wrote in your css:
.card-image{  height: 250px; }

I think you should have
.card-image{  height: 100%; }

because you limit the height